# A (proper) way to put minor ticks on duplicate y-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

**The problem:**

I try to create a simple plot with *two identical y-axes* (same numbers, same scale). However, I want one y-axis to have only *major* ticks, and another -- to have both *major* and *minor* ticks.

**The Minimal Working Example:**

I created  a *twin* y-axis, re-plotted the chart using this twin and set the locator for minor ticks.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator, AutoLocator


# matplotlib.__version__ = 3.3.3

dates = [date(2023, 3, 1),
date(2023, 3, 2),
date(2023, 3, 3),
date(2023, 3, 4),
date(2023, 3, 5)]

sample = np.arange(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 6), constrained_layout=True)
twin_y_ax = ax.twinx()

ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(AutoLocator())

ax.plot(dates, sample**2, linestyle = "dotted")

twin_y_ax.plot(dates, sample**2, linestyle = "dotted")
twin_y_ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(AutoLocator())
twin_y_ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())

for label in ax.get_xticklabels(which="major"):
    label.set(rotation=30, horizontalalignment="right")

plt.show()
```

This solution got me what I wanted, but what if I am plotting 10 lines. Do I need to re-plot all of them using a twin axis?

Suggestions for improvement are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why you would replot your data on `twin_y_ax`. IIUC you could simply copy `ax` limits and ticks and add the minor ticks:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator, AutoLocator

dates = [date(2023, 3, 1),
date(2023, 3, 2),
date(2023, 3, 3),
date(2023, 3, 4),
date(2023, 3, 5)]

sample = np.arange(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 6), constrained_layout=True)

# plot everything you need on ax
ax.plot(dates, sample**2, linestyle = "dotted")

# create a twin with same limits and labels
twin_y_ax = ax.twinx()
twin_y_ax.yaxis.set_ticks(ax.get_yticks())
twin_y_ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
# add minor ticks
twin_y_ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())

# also you can replace your loop with the following:
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=30, horizontalalignment="right")

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]